# Should answers be organized by "positive first" or "positive last"?

Tags: surveys, intuition, ordering

I'm designing a survey prompt for phones. The proposed orders are

**A - Question**

- Yes
- Maybe Later
- Never

**B - Question**

- Never
- Maybe Later
- Yes

I'm debating the order of the answers for it:

- Placing the positive answer at the top puts it further away from user's thumbs but makes the reading order a bit clearer.
- Placing the answer at the bottom puts it closer to user's thumbs but makes the reading order somewhat weird.

The idea is not to trick the user but to have the positive answer in the spot where they'd expect to find it.

Which is the more intuitive order?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I would say that having positive on the top would go well with the flow. I have seen this order been used in many places. For instance, Google Calendar events. If you have an event on a day, it asks you something like this:
"Going?   Yes - Maybe - No"
I have noticed this design at quite a few places. Hope this helps

Comment: I would go with positive on top. That's feels more natural to me.

Comment: Anyone got any research/studies, instead of gut feel?

Answer (score 2):

Just my thoughts looking at your wireframe, I think it depends whether you want to influence the answer of your user. Looking at it, it shows that you wanted them to answer YES (because it stands out from the two other options). However, if you want them to have unbiased answer towards how they feel/see, maybe putting the three options in similar color might be better... in my opinion.

In terms of order: I would say Negative (top) to Positive (bottom). If they really like to share it, they would simply click YES. But if they don't feel like it, they will make the extra effort to click NO.

Maybe adding colors to the three options would be fun. Just thinking out-of-the-box.

[image]

Comment: "I think it depends whether you want to influence the answer of your user", I would also add accommodating for the most common use case. IE. if most users click yes naturally, then have the button in an area that is most easily reached by the thumb.